# Union the table with itself, just with the columns reshuffled in pandas

Tags: pandas, union

I have a table with two columns - user1, user2. This is what I'd do in SQL:

```
SELECT user1, user2 from table
UNION
SELECT user2, user1 from table
```

Now I can easily group by column 1 to count how many friends each user has.

On a bigger table, I've tried this and it worked:

```
swap_list=['id','date','user2','user1','msg_count']
df2 = df2.reindex(columns=swap_list)

df2[['user1','user2']]=df2[['user2','user1']]

df3=pd.concat([df1,df2],sort=False)
```

But it looks clumsy and I don't know why I had to do it in so many steps. I actually espected to just be able to firstly swap users like that:

```
df2[['user1','user2']]=df2[['user2','user1']]
```

And then be able to do the union - but it didn't work. Neither did the sole reindex. Is there any way to do it in a more efficient manner?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to provide an example, but if I understand correctly:

```
out = pd.concat([df,
                 df[['user2','user1']].set_axis(['user1','user2'], axis=1),
                 ], sort=False)
```